# Navbar-text breaks out of Bootstrap navbar when resized to mobile size

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

https://jsfiddle.net/rpq1tf9x/

```
  <body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Italian Joe</a>
    </div>

      <p class="navbar-text text-center" id="NavHours" style="color:white; margin:1%; width: 220px;"> Open 6am to 5pm </p>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
```

As can be seen in this jsfiddle link, I have a basic bootstrap collapsing navbar that has an added text in the middle reading "Open 6am to 5pm", it's all fine and dandy on bigger screens but when you resize it to smaller screens it breaks the navbar. Anyone know why this is? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your paragraph needs to be **within** your `navbar-header`, rather than after it. SImply move the paragraph to the right DIV to correct this:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Italian Joe</a>
  <p class="navbar-text text-center" id="NavHours" style="color:white; margin:1%; width:220px;"> Open 6am to 5pm </p>
</div>
```

However, in order to display 'properly', you need to offset it from the top by removing `margin: 1%`, and give it more width (230px instead of 220px):

```
<p class="navbar-text text-center" id="NavHours" style="color:white; width:230px;"> Open 6am to 5pm </p>
```

I've created a new fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/oeLp84Lk/1/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Just what I needed

Comment: Glad to hear this answer solved the problem for you. Please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)